# Another picture puzzle _________

Tags: riddle, visual

A single word connects these images:

[image: A Worm]

[image: A Trickling Forrest Stream]

[image: The Mario Brothers]

[image: US Paper Currency]

[image: Sports Equipment]

[image: Coffee Stains]

[image: A Shed]

[image: A Bath Tub]

What is the word, and what are the connections?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the word is:

> Blood

1)

> Bloodworm  - the tubifex worm

2)

> Bloodstream - arteries and veins

3)

> Blood Brothers - a close bond

4)

> Blood Money - illicit funds

5)

> Bloodsport - Hunting, etc

6)

> Blood Stains - CSI evidence

7)

> Bloodshed  - (clever!) loss of blood

8)

> Bloodbath - Extreme violence

Comment: Hmm this seems really likely, but don't k ow how the title fits

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil "____line" as in ancestry?

Comment: @indubitablee I think you're spoiling too much here...

Comment: You got it.  Great explanations.  Sorry about the late reply.  +1 And yeah @BeastlyGerbil +1

Answer (score 4):

I think I have done this.

> The word that we are looking for is GAME.We have a famous video game series called "Worms".

Then,

> What we are shown is a stream. And we all now about Online Game Streaming. ;) (Android too...)

After that,

> We have the obvious Mario and Luigi Games.

Next

> Money, and we have a book called "The Money Game" by George Goodman

Then of course,

> We have all the things related to different sports or games like football, baseball, rugby, e.t.c

Interestingly next,

> What we are shown is a CUP...And what do we play GAMES for ?..some trophies or CUPS of course !

Penultimately,

> It's Housie...A Popular game again !

And finally,

> There is something called the Bath Game.You can read more about it by following this link www.scaryforkids.com/bath-game/

So...We are done I guess.

Happy Puzzling.Thank You. :)

Answer (score 2):

is it

> fishing
>  title: fishing line or alternatively fishing rod blank
>  fishing worm
>  river fishing
>  fishing plumbing, for depth of water
>  money fishing
>  sports fishing
>  fishing stains
>  fishing shed
>  fishing (bath) tub, to for children